# Get data even if one row is NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query to get users from the `users` table and also get the latest `time` (a timestamp) from the `logs` table where the entry is "login_ok". This is intended to show a list of users and the last time them logged in.

```
SELECT u.`id`, u.`email`, u.`firstname`, u.`lastname`, u.`type`, u.`creation_date`, MAX(l.`time`) as `last_login`
FROM `users` AS u
JOIN `logs` AS l ON u.id = l.user_id
WHERE l.`action` = 'login_ok'
AND `visible` = 1
GROUP BY u.`id`
ORDER BY u.`id` ASC
```

My issue here is: if the user has never logged in, the "login_ok" entry doesn't exists for that user, so the query cannot get that user data.

Is there any way to get all user data even if the `l.time` on `logs` doesn't exist? I tried with `JOIN`name_admin_users_log`AS l ON (l.`time`IS NOT NULL AND u.id = l.user_id)` but still not showing that new user without login log.

Comment: Make use of case statements like SELECT CASE WHEN USER_LOGGED IN THEN...ELSE SELECT CASE WHEN USER_LOGGED OUT...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a regular `JOIN` (which actually means `INNER JOIN`), and move the filter on `action = 'login_ok'` to that `LEFT JOIN` clause.

NB : from your query we cannot tell from which table the `visible` column comes from, so I assumed it is related to `users`...

```
SELECT
    u.id, 
    u.email,
    u.firstname,
    u.lastname,
    u.type,
    u.creation_date,
    MAX(l.time) as last_login
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN logs AS l
    ON u.id = l.user_id and l.action = 'login_ok' 
WHERE u.visible = 1
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.id ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about JOIN! This worked like a charm :) Thank you.

Comment: Welcome @JimmyAdaro ! Glad to help out

Answer (score 1):

Use a `left join`:

```
SELECT u.`id`, u.`email`, u.`firstname`, u.`lastname`, u.`type`, u.`creation_date`, MAX(l.`time`) as `last_login`
FROM `users` u LEFT JOIN
     `logs` l
     ON u.id = l.user_id AND l.`action` = 'login_ok'
WHERE u.`visible` = 1
GROUP BY u.`id`
ORDER BY u.`id` ASC;
```

This assumes that `visible` is in `users`.  If it is in `logs`, then that condition should also be in the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply ignore the `login_ok` and search for all values of `l.action`.

But if you want only values with `login_ok` and `null` then you can do:

```
WHERE l.`action` = 'login_ok' OR l.`action` is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use LEFT/RIGHT joins instead of JOIN(inner)
For example:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, l.time
FROM users u LEFT JOIN logs l
  ON u.id=l.user_id
```

In this case you'll get ALL the records from 'users'(the table on the left in the select: users - left, logs - right) and all records from the right('logs') table for which condition  u.id=l.user_id is true.

Finally you'll get something like this:

```
u.id   u.name   l.time
 1      John    10.00am
 2      Mary    2.15pm
 3      Mark    null
```